# Habilitar/Desabilitar campo SELECT

Tags: php, html5

```
<div class="form-group">                    
    <label>Tipo de Conta</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="banco" name="banco">
        <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
        <option value="0">Conta Corrente</option>
        <option value="1">Conta Poupança</option>
        <option value="2">Caixa (em espécie)</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">                    
    <label>Nome do Banco</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="banco" name="banco">
        <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
        <option value="0">Santander</option>
        <option value="1">Caixa</option>
        <option value="2">Banco do Brasil</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Gostaria de saber como habilitar/desabilitar o `SELECT` "Nome do Banco" de acordo com o "Tipo de Conta" selecionado. Exemplo:

Se o usuário selecionar o "Tipo de Conta" -> Conta Corrente, o campo "Nome do Banco" habilita;

Se o usuário selecionar o "Tipo de Conta" -> Caixa (em espécie), o campo "Nome do Banco" desabilita;

Comment: Tem que usar JavaScript para isso. Pesquise sobre eventos (mais especificamente o `change`) e tente fazer e poste o código. Se houver dificuldade poderemos tentar ajudar.

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisa, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um *event listener* `.change()` para escutar alterações no primeiro select e alterar o segundo.

Mas veja que você está usando o mesmo `id` e `name` nos dois selects. Isso é incorreto porque um `id` não pode ser repetido, e no caso do `name` repetido, se você submeter o formulário, irá pegar apenas o valor do segundo select.

Sugiro alterar o `id` e o `name` do primeiro select para `id="conta"` e `name="conta"`, evitando conflito entre os dois selects.

Outra sugestão é setar o segundo select com o atributo `disabled` para que ele já seja carregado desabilitado, e no script, quando o valor do primeiro select for igual a `vazio` ou `2`, desabilitar o segundo select. Você pode usar um ternário para isso, conforme usei no script abaixo.

Outra coisa é colocar o código dentro do evento `.ready()` (ou apenas `$(function(){});`), que aguarda o DOM ser carregado caso você esteja executando o script no `head` da página, mas é preciso também que o script seja carregado **após** o carregamento da biblioteca do jQuery:

```
<head>
   <script src="caminho do jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
   // aqui vem o script
   </script>
</head>
```

O código irá ficar assim:

```js
$(function(){
   $("#conta").change(function(){
      $("#banco")
      .prop(
         "disabled",
         this.value == 2 || !this.value ? true : false
      );
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">                    
    <label>Tipo de Conta</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="conta" name="conta">
        <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
        <option value="0">Conta Corrente</option>
        <option value="1">Conta Poupança</option>
        <option value="2">Caixa (em espécie)</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">                    
    <label>Nome do Banco</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="banco" name="banco" disabled>
        <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
        <option value="0">Santander</option>
        <option value="1">Caixa</option>
        <option value="2">Banco do Brasil</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, implementei o código e funcionou. Muito obrigado pelas dicas também...

Comment: Olá Luiz! Tá por aí?!

Answer (score 3):

Apenas fiz uma alteração no `value` do select, pois caso inicie em **0**, toda vez que ele fizer a verificação e encontrar o valor `""`, irá tratar da mesma forma. Para isso, Inseri com as legendas abaixo:

---

CC: **C**onta **C**orrente

CP: **C**onta **P**oupança

CE: **C**aixa **E**spécie

---

Tente da seguinte forma:

```js
function habilitarCampos() {
 if($("#banco").val() == 'CC') {
  $("#nomebanco").prop('disabled', false);
 } else {
   $("#nomebanco").prop('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">                    
    <label>Tipo de Conta</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="banco" name="banco" onchange='habilitarCampos()'>
        <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
        <option value="CC">Conta Corrente</option>
        <option value="CP">Conta Poupança</option>
        <option value="CE">Caixa (em espécie)</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">                    
    <label>Nome do Banco</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="nomebanco" name="banco">
        <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
        <option value="0">Santander</option>
        <option value="1">Caixa</option>
        <option value="2">Banco do Brasil</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Vou implementar no código e te falo se funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @luizgparaujo, sem problemas, se funcionar, vote na resposta e selecione esta resposta como a solução por favor :)

Comment: Fiz a implementação no código, porém não consegui fazer funcionar. Criei um arquivo JavaScript e inseri a função habilitarCampos, depois inseri o script no meu caso no head, e ajustei o restante do código, não sei se faltou algo...

Comment: Estranho... Deveria funcionar... Tente colocar o `script` abaixo dos forms, veja se funciona